# confusion regarding toggle() effect and event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two div elements "trigger" and "target". I was looking for a mechanism where every time "trigger" is clicked, a script animates the height of "target". However I need it to toggle between 0px and 100px. After some research I found [this](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

On searching a little I found the following script

```
$("#trigger").toggle(function(){
    $("#target").animate({height:40},200);
},function(){
    $("#target").animate({height:10},200);
});
```

However it didnt seem to work.. after some more searching I came across the following script

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {$("#trigger").click(function()
 {
  $('#target').toggle(
function()
 {
  $('#target').animate({height: "250"}, 1500);
 },
function()
  {
   $('#target').animate({height: "0"}, 1500);
  });
 });
});
```

and this didn't work either. The element does animate but along with the height, the width and opacity would also animate. Further research brought me to [this](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) effect. So basically there are two toggle(). in jquery, and i'm confused about how each is used. All I want to do is animate the height of one element with a toggle when another element is clicked. I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: jQuery's `.toggle()` function had two different forms. The one that switched every time you clicked it and one that toggled the visibility of the element. The first one was removed a while ago.

Comment: ya, removed in 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Oh I was not aware about that. That's exactly what had confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a variable like `var trigger = false;`

```
var trigger = false;

$("#trigger").click(function(){
    if(!trigger) {
        $("#target").animate({height:40},200);
        trigger = true;
    }
    else {
        $("#target").animate({height:10},200);
        trigger = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `toggleClass` instead:

```
$("#trigger").click(function() {
  $(".target").toggleClass("higher");
});
```

in your css you then use:

```
.target {
  height:50px;
  background-color:#f00;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s;
  -moz-transition: height 1s;
  -ms-transition: height 1s;
  -o-transition: height 1s;
  transition: height 1s;
}
.higher {
  height:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JSfa3/